# Music scanning library for insanely long time

Tags: music

I'm running Juno, and I have a very large music library, about 290gb with a mixture of mp3 and flac. I really want to try the Elementary OS Music player, but scanning my library is taking an ungodly long time. It's now been scanning for about 34 hours and is only 3/4th of the way through. I don't recall having this issue with Loki.

At first I had my music library on an NTFS partition, but Noise would only scan for a little while then crash, then I read that NTFS was very slow on Linux, so I figured moving the library would solve my problem. So I copied my entire music library to an ext4 formatted USB 3 drive that is normally very fast.

Music/Noise no longer crashes when scanning, but now the scan is been going for over a full day and still not completed. Does anyone have any idea why this could possibly be taking so long? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

According to issues already reported by other users on the Music Github page (see [here](https://github.com/elementary/music/issues/506) and [here](https://github.com/elementary/music/issues/502)), slow scanning of large library files is currently quite typical to this app and probably has nothing to do with any particular filesystem.

Comment: Thanks, well at least it's known about. I hope it gets fixed. I've switched to Rhythmbox for the time being.